# Show XML Data using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have data pagenumber.xml data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Search>
<Pages Count="40">
<Page Number="1">Data in page1</Page>
<Page Number="2">Data in page2</Page>
<Page Number="3">Data in page3</Page>
<Page Number="4">Data in page4</Page>
<Page Number="5">Data in page5</Page>
</Pages>
</Search>
```

How to show data in my xml file using PHP
it's my code to show xml data, but still error in show page data

```
<?php
$dataxml = simplexml_load_file('pagenumber.xml');

foreach($dataxml->Pages as $buku)
{
   echo "Pages count: ".$buku['Count']."<br>";
   echo "Data in page 1: --> i don't know how to show the data
   echo "Data in page 2: --> i don't know how to show the data
   echo "Data in page 3: --> i don't know how to show the data
   echo "Data in page 4: --> i don't know how to show the data
   echo "Data in page 5: --> i don't know how to show the data
}
?>
```

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dataxml = simplexml_load_file('pagenumber.xml');

foreach($dataxml->Pages as $buku)
{
   echo "Pages count: ".$buku['Count']."<br/>";
   foreach($buku->Page as $page) 
   {
      echo "Data in page ";
      echo $page['Number'];
      echo ": --> ";
      echo $page;
      echo "<br/>";
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dataxml = simplexml_load_file('pagenumber.xml');
foreach($dataxml->Pages as $buku)
{
   echo $buku->Page[0]; 
   echo $buku->Page[2]; 
   echo $buku->Page[3]; 
   echo $buku->Page[4]; 
   echo $buku->Page[5]; 
}
?>
```